# WordPress jQuery issue, Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I've been searching all over stackoverflow and Google and still haven't solved this issue. it says Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

jquery is already at the header and the slipper.min js at footer. Not sure what to do after it.

Here's the website, you can inspect it here. 
https://ig.design/sliderfix/wordpress/shop/loft/

Can you please let me know what the problem is?

Thanks

Comment: _“and the slipper.min js at footer”_ - it is not _only_ there, it is also in the head already, first thing after the opening `<head>` tag … and at _that_ point there is no jQuery, because that gets embedded only later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have connected slippry.min.js in the header, jQuery is connected below. (You can view the source of the page that you see this problem)

Use in functions.php to connect slippry in footer after jquery:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'slippry', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slippry/1.4.0/slippry.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), null, true );
```

Update:
You also connected slippry.min.js 2 times in footer and header.

You also need to add a function to call the slider after connecting the jquery and slippry.min.js

```
(function(){
    $('selector').slippry();
}());
```

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress plays it safe and keeps jQuery within `window.jQuery` object (and not `$`)

either explicitly tell wp to use $ or wrap your code in a closure

```
;(function($){
    // in here $ points to jQuery and does not pollute the global scope

)(jQuery);
```